# Dynamic scrollbar with offcanvas menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

My offcanvas menu has a short main menu with a scrolling sub-menu.  The problem is that I don't want the main menu to scroll, but I *might* want the sub-menu to scroll, because the sub-menu is dynamic.  I'd prefer a CSS solution but if there is no good solution, jQuery is fine.

I've tried to set the submenu as `display: none;` and then set it to `display: block;` when it becomes active, but this prevents the animation from working (in chrome) for some reason.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1jy65n4w/1/)

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="blah">One</li>
    <li class="blah">One</li>
    <li class="blah">One</li>
    <li class="blah">
        One Sub
        <ul>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="blah">One</li>
    <li class="blah">One</li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
ul
{
    padding:0;margin:0;
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}
ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -250px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease all;
    transition: .5s ease all;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 0;
}
ul .active ul
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
    transform: translateX(250px);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.blah:not(.active)').on('click', function()
{
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('li li').on('click', function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.active').toggleClass('active');
});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `Height: 100%` of all the sub-menus and using the overflow on the `ul` elements themselves solved the problem quite simply.  Next was removing the scrolling for parent containers when child containers were active.

This also solves that the scrollbar is specific to each menu height, not all menus.

[JsFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/1jy65n4w/5/)

Updated CSS

```
html,body{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;height:100%;}
ul
{
    padding:0;margin:0;
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.noscroll
{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Updated JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('li:not(.close)').on('click', function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).closest('ul').addClass('noscroll');
    });
    $('li.close').on('click', function(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.noscroll').removeClass('noscroll');
    });
})
```